# Externalizing properties for Spring Boot

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I know there are quite a few threads on this, but none have solved my issue yet.  I have a Spring Boot app that was running in Eclipse and I externalized the parameters in order to deploy to an external Tomcat and keep the properties out of the war.  I moved my application.properties out of src/main/resources and into APP_ROOT/config. In catalina.sh, I added this:

```
 JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=local  -Dspring.config.location=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/"
```

The external build is working fine; however, now it is not starting in Eclipse any longer.  I replicated what I did in Tomcat by adding spring.config.location and spring.profiles.active to the VM arguments in the Launch Configuration.

During bootstrapping, it registers an Oracle driver (not the same version I specify in my properties file) and then stops.  If I add:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

to my config class so that driver isn't auto-registered, then I get:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]
```

The odd part is that I tried putting my application.properties back in src/main/resources and removing the VM arguments and I'm getting the same behaviors.  This is what I am seeing on startup without excluding the DataSourceAutoConfiguration.  Any ideas?

```
2016-09-30 11:44:59.661  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.usp.mct.MctApplication               : Starting MctApplication on cici-mac.local with PID 5150 (/Users/cici/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE/mct.usp.org/target/classes started by cici in /Users/cici/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE/mct.usp.org)
2016-09-30 11:44:59.663  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.usp.mct.MctApplication               : The following profiles are active: local
2016-09-30 11:44:59.713  INFO 5150 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@550ee7e5: startup date [Fri Sep 30 11:44:59 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-30 11:45:01.005  INFO 5150 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-09-30 11:45:01.019  INFO 5150 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2016-09-30 11:45:01.088  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
2016-09-30 11:45:01.089  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-09-30 11:45:01.091  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-09-30 11:45:01.127  INFO 5150 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-09-30 11:45:01.598  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2016-09-30 11:45:01.749  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@70972170
2016-09-30 11:45:01.749  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [[B] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@70972170
2016-09-30 11:45:01.750  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [Byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@69fe0ed4
2016-09-30 11:45:01.750  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@69fe0ed4
2016-09-30 11:45:02.181  INFO 5150 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-09-30 11:45:02.984  INFO 5150 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-09-30 11:45:02.992  INFO 5150 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-09-30 11:45:03.059  INFO 5150 --- [           main] org.usp.mct.MctApplication               : Started MctApplication in 3.796 seconds (JVM running for 4.181)
2016-09-30 11:45:03.060  INFO 5150 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@550ee7e5: startup date [Fri Sep 30 11:44:59 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-30 11:45:03.061  INFO 5150 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2016-09-30 11:45:03.063  INFO 5150 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I blew away my repo and then re-cloned.  Still have to get it working with external parameters instead of src/main/resources/application.properties, but at least I am back to square one.